# Unable to open custom intent from google assistant in app actions

Tags: android, flutter, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I'm trying to Implement custom intent in the app actions following the link below link
[Custom intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/custom-intents)

The code I have written is

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="scheduleApptQueries">
        <item>schedule appointment with $apptType</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name = "appointment_user_name">schedule appointment with $apptType</string>
</resources>
```

shortcuts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <capability
        android:name="custom.actions.intent.SCHEDULE_APPOINTMENT"
        app:queryPatterns="@array/scheduleApptQueries">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.quads.gg_app"
            android:targetClass="com.example.gg_app.MainActivity" >
        <url-template android:value="https://example.com/appt{apptType}" />
        <parameter android:name="apptType" android:key="apptType" />
    </intent>
    </capability>

    <shortcut
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/appointment_user_name"
    android:shortcutId="DRIVERS_LICENSE">
    <capability-binding android:key="custom.actions.intent.SCHEDULE_APPOINTMENT">
    <parameter-binding
        android:key="apptType"
        android:value="@arrays/scheduleApptQueries" />
    </capability-binding>
        </shortcut>

</shortcuts>
```

when I create the preview in the android studio app actions tool I'm able to view the custom.actions.intent.SCHEDULE_APPOINTMENT intent and I'm able to retrieve the data from the parameters but when I give the command to google assistant that "open testapp and schedule appointment with dom" the google assistant is failing to detect the command.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm struggling with a similar problem although for now I'm testing the standard action actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE. From all the documentation I read, you need to build a release version of your app, upload it to Google Play, at least the "internal testing" area, be logged in Google Play tester and on your physical device with the same Google account, and in Google Play for your app, under Settings - Advanced, turn on the "Integrate my services..." option. Then it's supposed to work. But it doesn't for me either...

Comment: @gregko I have tried all the steps you have mentioned. Still, I didn't get the solution. If you come with the solution please let me know.

Comment: @thinkcode, what's your assistant's and device's language when you are testing your custom intent-command?

Comment: @CaptainJacky English

Comment: @thinkcode, is it `en-US` in both device's language and App Acton's Locale window? Because it's the only language available for custom actions.

Comment: Try adding the word "app" in your voice. I mean, "open testapp APP and schedule appointment with dom"

Comment: Also, I am a bit new on the Assistant but I read that you should add android:mimeType to the parameter. According to the Custom Intents docs in your link: For each parameter, provide the supported schema.org type that best describes the meaning of the parameter. For example, you can use https://schema.org/Date to describe a date you expect to receive: android:mimeType="https://schema.org/Date"